# ¿como obtener valores en un MULTISELECT mediante JSON?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, json

tengo un campo dni y un multiselect tecnologia,en tecnologia le añadi una funcion para que se muestre con cuadros de check()los cuales quiero mostrar mediante JSON, pero no me arrastra nada, estaba pensando añadirle un ajax dentro de la funcion, pero no sabria como hacerlo

```
<body>
  <center>
    <br/>
  <div id="contenedor">
    <br/><br/>
    <label>DNI</label>
    <input type="text" id="dni"> 

    <select  id="tecnologia" name="tecnologia[]" multiple="multiple" size="5">
     <option value="2g">2G</option> 
      <option value="3g">3G</option> 
     <option value="4g">4G</option> 
     <option value="tdd">TDD</option>
      </select>

     <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#tecnologia').multiselect({
        buttonText: function(options, select){
          console.log(select[0].length);
          if (options.length===0) {
            return 'sin Seleccion';
          }
          if (options.length===select[0].length) {
            return 'todos ('+select[0].length+')';
          }
          else if(options.length>=4){
            return options.length+'seleccionados';
          }else{

            var labels=[];
            console.log(options);
            options.each(function(){
              labels.push($(this).val());
            });
            return labels.join(', ')+'';
          }

        }
      });
    });
</script>
</br>

  </br></br>
    <button onclick="anadir();">Añadir</button>
    <input type="submit" onclick="buscar()" value="buscar">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

en este punto .js realizo el ajax

```
function buscar(){

    var parametros={"dni": $("#dni").val(),}

    $.ajax({

            type: 'post',
            url: '../lunes-2/buscardatos.php',
            data: parametros,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(d){

                $.each(d[0].split(","), function(i,e){
                    $("#tecnologia option[value='"+e+"']").prop("selected",true);
                });

            }
        });
}

y aca arrastro los valores de mi base de datos mediante JSON

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("archivos",$con);

$dni=$_POST["dni"];
$rs=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clie  WHERE dni='$dni'");

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);

$datos_a_enviar = array($row['tecnologia']);
echo json_encode($datos_a_enviar);
?>
```

lo que trato es que me muestre los valores de mi base de datos en el select MULTIPLE, pero como estoy añadiendo una funcion en el body(que funciona de la mejor manera) no sabria como modificar el codigo alli para que cuando ingrese mi dni y de click en buscar me muestre las opciones que fueron seleccionadas y estan almacenadas en mi BD

Comment: probaste usando `$("#tecnologia").val()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que refrescar el multiselect.  Intenta asi:

```
$.ajax({

        type: 'post',
        url: '../lunes-2/buscardatos.php',
        data: parametros,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(d){

            $.each(d[0].split(","), function(i,e){
                $("#tecnologia option[value='"+e+"']").prop("selected",true);
            });
            $("#technologia").multiselect("refresh");
        }
    });
```